# How to automatically set password to lowercase if user key in uppercase letters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

My goal is to set the username to lowercase if user accidentally key in uppercase letters in angular2.

For an example, 
i set the user name to admin , if user key in Admin. It should recognize as "admin" rather than "Admin".

I have tried to add .toLowerCase but it is not working correctly and i am usure how should i code it..

This is my original code i have and it is working, Admin must key in as "admin" inside user and it will work.

But what i am working at is. i want to make it not key sensetive. so if admin key in as "Admin" . he is able to log in as well without modifying my code.

```
loginCallback: (params: any)=>{
        if(params.user == "admin" && params.pass == "demo")  this._router.navigate(["/App/Version/3-0-0"])
        else this._errorSvc.setErrorMsg("You have entered an invalid username or password.");
    }
```

As mentioned above. I tried using this, i just simply added .toLowerCase. but when i tried to log in as "admin" or "Admin" . Nothing is working.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks .

```
loginCallback: (params: any)=>{
        if(params.user.toLowerCase == "admin" && params.pass == "demo")  this._router.navigate(["/App/Version/3-0-0"])
        else this._errorSvc.setErrorMsg("You have entered an invalid username or password.");
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Password should b case-sensitive. You should encourage complexity of the password (alpha-numeric, with special characters, including both uppercase and lower case letters and and long passwords). The goal should be protecting the user by improving the security of the password. Week passwords are easier to crack.

Comment: Sorry, what i tried to modify is actually for username not password. But thanks anw . will take note of that . :)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing parentheses after toLowerCase().

Comment: Thanks, i rectified the problem . :)